# How to export the font configuration of Xcode to Sublime?

Tags: sublime-text-2, xcode

I like the font configuration of my Xcode. So, how to export the font configuration of Xcode to Sublime?

Comment: @slhck thanks. BTW, is there a GUI font configuration for sublime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no export option for this… you need to just set it in Sublime. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> and here, in your `Preferences.sublime-settings`, add:

```
{
  "font_face": "Menlo",
  "font_size": 11.0
}
```

Menlo Regular, 11pt is what Xcode uses by default.

To my knowledge there is no GUI configuration for fonts in Sublime—actually, there's little GUI functionality with regard to these core aspects, apart from switching the color scheme.